# Which Event Fire When Press Undo in Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using **Xamarin Studio** for Android Development.

I have 2 Activity(Screens). 1st is A Activity and 2nd B Activity.

First lunch A Activity then user open 2nd Activity. Then user press Back(Undo) button of mobile. Then I want to refresh A Activity. Which event is fire of A Activity when user press back button.

1. Screen A --> (Open)Screen B
2. Screen B(Press Back) --> Screen A [Here I want refresh]

Reason is that: I'm showing data from DB. That's why I want to refresh again on press back from 2nd Activity but refresh should be 1st Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you first open an activity

```
onCreate() -> onStart() -> onResume()
```

methods will be executed,

Then when you start another activity and come back to this activity again with back button,

```
onRestart() -> onStart() -> onResume()
```

methods will be executed,

Depends on your need, you can use onStart() method to refresh your data, after executing onStart() method, activity will be visible to user but can't interact, onResume() state user can interact to activity.

Answer (score 1):

When you go back from B to A.

```
onStart();
```

Is also called in A. Thus you can add your refresh code to it like:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
  super.onStart();
 // your code
}
```

Comment: You are right but when I implement this event. I'm facing exception and application is closing. I Have implement same this.

`protected override void OnResume()
        {
            GetRequestInfoList();
        }`

Comment: You didn't call super.onResume();. The android documentation states that you have to call the super class first.

Comment: onResume(); is calling when I called to B Activity. Not calling when I press back button from B Activity. onRestart() is working but not perfect. It's restarting 2 time.